# Afraid about SSH on my Linux system

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, system-compromise

I've checked my Linux server (Centos 6) with rkhunter. I found the following in rkhunter log

```
[14:38:54]   Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed          [ Warning ]
[14:38:54] Warning: The SSH configuration option 'Protocol' has not been set.
           The default value may be '2,1', to allow the use of protocol version 1.
```

When i checked with `/etc/ssh/` I found 2 config files, `sshd_config` and `ssh_config`.

ssh_config last modified on 21-Sep-2013 (22:30).

rkhunter result of 21-Sep-2013 (04:20)

```
[04:10:40]   Checking if SSH root access is allowed          [ Not set ]
[04:10:40]   Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed          [ Not allowed ]
```

I'm worried that my server maybe compromised.

**Update**

After run clamav scan on server, I found `/usr/sbin/sasluster` (*Stealth MultiFunctional IrcBot*).

How do I remove it? What does it mean?

Comment: To disable `protocol v1` and enforce `protocol v2` only, you can follow this guide http://support.hoststore.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=229

Comment: As a note, having both sshd_config and ssh_config is totally normal provided you have both the "server" and "client" installed. sshd_config is the config file for sshd (the daemon) and ssh_config is the config file for your ssh client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @LucasKauffman No, [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) is not a duplicate (but Kumar, this is what you need to do). This question is not about a compromised server. (Well, it turns out that the server is compromised, but that's not what the question is about.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going by what you originally posted about SSH, there is no evidence there that your server is compromised. It would be quite a round-the-houses way of breaking SSH for an attacker to resort to a default configuration.

This is simply a warning message that your `sshd` or `ssh` might be misconfigured. RKHunter could not find a configuration value for the `Protocol` key, and is simply warning you that the default might not be great for security.

You should edit your `sshd_config` and `ssh_config` files and add a `Protocol 2` line to avoid getting this warning in the future by explicitly disabling protocol 1.

---

So you have evidence that your SSH config file has altered. This is almost certainly the result of an update, if someone has run an `apt-get upgrade` and then said `yes` when asked about a config overwrite, this can happen.

You should check the rest of your `sshd_config` however just to make sure that everything is as it should be, particularly disallowing `root` login. Also check `/etc/passwd` to see if any new users have been created, and `/etc/sudo` for the same reasons.

---

If your server does turn out to be compromised, this is unlikely to be related to the warning about SSH.

Comment: Please check added details about rkhunter log. Actually we not did anything in that mean time. That's why...

Comment: @ This is additional thing I got in log, Warning: File '/usr/bin/chattr' has the immutable-bit set. Didn't have this in previous log in 21-Sep-2013 (04:20).