# My wifi has been hacked

Tags: attacks

The hacker has complete control of my computer; opening and shutting programs at will.  Deleting files that display the remote user ip address.  We have changed the password several times; but no luck.  Originally there was a remote sharing program that Geek Squad removed; however, the situation still continues.  Is there any hope?

Comment: You may find useful advices (here)[https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server]

Comment: This is not a user support forum. Can you ask your question with technical details and explain why it is a general, recurrent information security problem?

Comment: Changing your password did not help; maybe the attacker left a keylogger on your system?

Comment: Why do you say your wifi was hacked when you only discuss computer problems?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off your own computer. Then, **from a different computer**, in this order:

1. Change the router admin default password
2. Change the wi-fi password
3. Download a live distro that will clean the operating system of your own computer (you did not specify if you're running Windows, Linux or OSX)

Then **without connecting your own computer to the wi-fi**:

1. Boot up with the live distro
2. Clean as best as you can
3. Back up your data on a removable disk

Now you have a choice: either connect to the wifi and update your antivirus and run whatever you need to finish cleaning up, or wipe everything and re-install.

Note that this is a best guess of a likely scenario. It is still possible that your home router is vulnerable to certain attacks, in this case you might want to update its firmware or change router, but we're into the realm of speculations here - Your Mileage May Vary.

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible that your WiFi has been hacked it's not likely your computer was taken over using a compromised network device. You could have been attacked when on a public wifi, which would not require a compromise of the network device.

What is more likely is that your computer was cracked using malware that was sent to you as an email attachment, or you visited a website which used unpatched vulnerabilities to crack your system. These are much more common attacks which do not require anyone to access your network.

If your wifi was hacked then you need to get control of your network back before fixing your computer, or it will just get cracked again. How to do that depends on your make and model.

To fix your system you'll simply have to wipe it and start over, it's simply not possible completely clean a system with any level of assurance. Be sure to do that on a trustworthy network though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think someone hacked your PC through WiFi. 
I think your PC is infected with a Trojan (possibly Remote Administration Tool) so changing password is not a solution at all. I suggest you to clean the PC with good anti virus software in safe mode or reinstall the whole system if necessary.

Answer (score -3):

Disconnect from the Internet, back up your data, reinstall your machine and finally install a good antimalware on it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DeerHunter how does this not answer the question ? Reinstalling the machine is actually the only correct answer.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the kind responses.  Perhaps it's not the wifi; but I do know that when I login Kaspersky flags my account saying your wireless internet is not secured.  Also, my isp says that they have seen other MAC hardward addresses accessing my wifi.  Thanks again;/All help appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry one other thing; the geek squad also told me that there was no malaware found. Only remote access software; which they had removed.

Comment: Well if you have a few laptops, tablets and other mobile devices connected to your WiFi network, then each of these devices has a MAC address that is accessing your network. Remote Administration Tool is a Malware.

Comment: Thank you @André Daniel , you are the only one who seems to know what he's talking about.