# Virus: Images get replaced on website

Tags: malware, web-browser, virus, antivirus

I have installed Windows 7 again on my laptop with Chrome as browser. The problem is that on different websites I visit, the actual images of the website get replaced with out of context images. It happens quite often. Is it some virus? How can I remove it?

Comment: This question is vague and too broad. Which images do get replaced with what? Do you own the network? Maybe there's a pattern? Maybe you installed some adware stuff? Maybe maybe maybe...

Comment: @HamZa The original images that the website has used get replaced with some random images. However, if I refresh the same page then sometimes the original images appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 1):

Check on another device to see if the same behaviour occurs.

I don't believe removal of malware is the scope of this forum. However, I'd recommend you do an virus scan, check your BHOs and Addins on your browser.

Comment: This happens on all devices in same LAN. I have used virus scan but it detected no virus.

Comment: Interesting, could you turn off your devices which you may think be infected then use your phone to do it.

Comment: Maybe your router is infected with some malware.

Comment: Try resetting your router to clear any virus / malware settings.You may need to ask your ISP for your internet connection information after you do this