# Browser hijacked on Debian

Tags: web-browser, browser-hijacking

Seems someone has setup something in my system. I have several ports on localhost sending outbound communications. When in Firefox I type web.whatsapp.com for whatsapp web, I get a browser re-direct.

Anybody knows some good approach about cleaning this sort of stuff from the sytem? I'm on a Debian Jessie 64bits.

Here are some suspicous connections on netsat -tulpan output:

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:50465       198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED 4556/firefox
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:35162       151.101.65.69:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:46103       198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 4556/firefox
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:35191       151.101.65.69:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:44444       200.40.28.147:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:53077       151.101.193.69:80       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:44745       151.101.1.69:80         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:53072       151.101.193.69:80       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:50464       198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED 4556/firefox
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:39236       192.0.73.2:443          ESTABLISHED 4556/firefox
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:42522       104.16.112.18:443       ESTABLISHED 4556/firefox
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:44447       64.233.190.102:443      ESTABLISHED 4556/firefox
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:35163       151.101.65.69:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:48172       200.40.28.16:80         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:45010       64.233.190.95:80        TIME_WAIT   -

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: Why do you think they are suspicious? I'm seeing StackExchange IPs for most of that list, plus a couple Google, and a Cloudflare ... Removing the netstat output, all you have is a whatsapp redirect that you don't provide details for.

Comment: Perhaps it's a (potentially malicious) firefox extension.

Answer (score 2):

> When in Firefox I type web.whatsapp.com for whatsapp web, I get a browser re-direct.

That is concerning and *could* be an indicator for malware (adware) or a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

> Anybody knows some good approach about cleaning this sort of stuff from the sytem?

Since you have only been giving generic information about what's going on I can only redirect you to a generic answer on [how to deal with a compromised server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

> Here are some suspicious connections on netsat -tulpan output:
>
> ```
> tcp 0 0 192.168.1.2:50465 198.252.206.25:80 ESTABLISHED 4556/firefox
> (...)
> ```

There is nothing inherently suspicious about the presented output. What you are seeing are several open TCP connections which is absolutely normal for an active browser session. The target ports `80` and `443` indicate that you are probably communicating with web services.

You can lookup the IP addresses online or perform a reverse DNS query, for example via the [`host(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/host) command, to find out more about the servers you are connected to. For example:

```
$ host 198.252.206.25
25.206.252.198.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer stackoverflow.com.
```

As you can see the first IP seems to belong to *stackoverflow*. That said, if you assume you have been compromised you should also be aware that all analysis from within the affected system is unreliable.