# Is the PHP BB code extension safe against XSS?

Tags: web-application, php, xss, bbcode

Bad home brew implementations of BB code (especially in PHP) are a common source of  XSS vulnerabilities. Usually they rely on a bunch of regexes, a tool that is [not fit for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

But lo and behold - there is a [PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) for converting BB code into HTML! The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php) contains code like this, that raises question about escaping attribute values, `javascript:` URLs, etc.:

```
'url' => array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_OPTARG,
            'open_tag'=>'<a href="{PARAM}">', 'close_tag'=>'</a>',
            'default_arg'=>'{CONTENT}',
            'childs'=>'b,i'),
```

Is this extention reasonably safe against XSS? What sort of usage of it can be considered safe? What features should be avoided or used with care? Should I plug the output into HTML purifier just to be sure?