# How can I find cryptomining malware on my vBulletin forum?

Tags: malware

I‌ have a vBulletin 4.2.3 forum which is apparently infected by cryptomining malware because whenever I‌ open a tab, I get very high CPU‌ load, and the load drops as soon as I close the tab.

I'm wondering how can I‌ find the culprit code and remove it?

Comment: Removing malware will not help unless you find out how the malware was added to your system in the first place. Otherwise your system will be infected shortly again. See also [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: It is possible that you just have buggy JS code and not an infection... You need to examine the JS code that is running in the browser to see what it is doing.