# System Infected: Trojan.Naid Activity

Tags: antivirus, windows-server, trojan, tomcat

We have Tomcat 6 in the production server with Symantec Endpoint Protection on windows server 2008 server datacenter.
Symantec showing following lines in logs

> [SID: 27068] System Infected: Trojan.Naid Activity 2 attack blocked.
>   Traffic has been blocked for this application:
>   \DEVICE\HARDDISKVOLUME4\TOMCAT 6.0\BIN\TOMCAT6.EXE

It is clearly showing system Infected. What is Trojan.Naid exactly? What could be exactly infected in our system? 
Whether Windows and Tomcat combination is dangerous in production servers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: That question don't have specific answer related to System Infected: Trojan.Naid Activity

Comment: Are you aware that anti-virus sites have pages that document what their findings mean? https://www.symantec.com/security-center/writeup/2012-061518-4639-99

Comment: The vendor provides the documentation you are looking for for `Trojan.Naid`. The alert tells you what is infected. Your question about whether Windows and Tomcat combination is dangerous is an odd question when [Tomcat 6 went end-of-life in 2016](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-60-eol.html). Tomcat is not the problem, but the fact that you are using an out of support piece of software. Tomcat is now at 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/attacksignatures/detail.jsp?asid=27068):

> Trojan.Naid is a Trojan horse that opens a back door on the compromised computer.
>
> When the Trojan is executed, it creates the following files:
>
> %UserProfile%\AppMgmt.dll %Windir%\Temp\uid.ax
>
> The Trojan creates the following registry entries:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Services\AppMgmt\"Start" = "2"
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Services\AppMgmt\Parameters\"ServiceDll"
>   = "%UserProfile%\AppMgmt.dll" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Services\AppMgmt\"Type" = "272"
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Services\AppMgmt\"FailureActions"
>   = "[BINARY DATA]"
>
> The Trojan may create one of the following services so that it runs
>   every time Windows starts:
>
> AppMgmt BITS
>
> The Trojan collects the following system information from the
>   compromised computer:
>
> domain name unique identifier (UID)
>
> The Trojan utilises its own custom communications protocol to connect
>   to the following IP address over port 443:
>   219.90.117.132
>
> The Trojan then opens a back door on the compromised computer.

So you should inspect at least mentioned paths, keys and services.

But trojan could be modified, so I'd also recommend to inspect network connections using `netstat` or Process Monitor and other tools from [Sysinternals Suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/).