# Google Cloud Platform may have been compromised and used for cryptocurrency mining

Tags: google, google-cloud-platform

How to detect where the issue on my server is, and whether the server is being used for cryptocurrency mining?

I just received an email from Google and my server stopped working.

> Dear Developer,
>
> Our systems identified that your Google Cloud Platform / API Project
> ID  HelloWorld (id: fair-solution-555555) may have been compromised
> and used for  cryptocurrency mining.
>
> This activity was detected as originating from IP xyz and VM ID
> 123456:us-east1-b to destination IP abc on remote  port
> 6233 between 2020-10-22 23:14 and 2020-10-22 23:22 (Pacific
> Time), though it may still be ongoing.
>
> We recommend that you review this activity to determine if it is
> intended.  Cryptocurrency mining is often an indication of the use of
> fraudulent  accounts and payment instruments, and we require
> verification in order to  mine cryptocurrency on our platform.
>
> Therefore if you wish to continue engaging in cryptocurrency mining,
> and  you haven't already applied for an Invoiced Billing Account
> (support.google.com/cloud/contact/apply_for_invoiced_billing), please
> do  so. Additional information is available in the Cloud Security Help
> Center(support.google.com/cloud/answer/6262505).
>
> If you believe your project has been compromised, we recommend that
> you  secure all your instances
> (https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6262505), which may require
> uninstalling and then re-installing your project.
>
> To better protect your organization from misconfiguration and access
> the  best of Google's threat detection, you may consider enabling
> Security  Command Center (SCC) for your organization. To learn more
> about SCC visit  `https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center`.
>
> Once you have fixed the issue, please respond to this email. If
> the  behavior is intentional, please explain so that we do not ping
> you again  for this activity. Please do not hesitate to reach out to
> us if you have  questions.
>
> Should you require further assistance or information related to this
> matter, don't hesitate to email us and we'll get back to you as soon
> as we're able. In the best effort to help out, feel free to provide us
> your best contact number as well as the best time to contact you.
> Looking forward to your response.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Hanna Google Cloud Platform Support

Comment: There is nothing known about your server, the configuration, the installed software and its versions, suspicious log entries etc. This makes it in my opinion  a duplicate of the also very generic [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: That is not related to my question buddy

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad Why not? Someone hacked your server and installed a bitcoin miner. The other question is about what to do when someone hacks your server.

Comment: That answer is not about bitcoin miner, I'm sure some one else faced the issue and may be he can guide better, it is not good to close the question if you don't know the answer. Also I'm sure near future most of the user facing this issue so instead of reading that 20 minutes  long answer and most of the related to don't panic I want to do some productive action so server can be restored.