# Where does elp.php come from?

Tags: php, htaccess

From yesterday on, all my sites (one and same hosting) has an elp.php-file in the root-folder of every domain.

This file is publicly open and does show a list of all files, with possibility to edit all files (even config.php etc...)
I am sure this was a hack... but how to find where it came from?
I deleted all of them, but how to force them forbidden? Or avoid them?

1. I have changed .htaccess to forbid "elp.php" in every domain.
2. I removed them all
3. ... ????

Google didnt find my things, except an amount of /Index-list etc.

Comment: It is impossible to find out how your system was compromised based on this information - [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: What you've told us is only this: that a new PHP file is showing up on your root directory. From this one fact, we can't tell you what weakness your site or hoster has that would have allowed this. That's like asking "someone broke into my house and I saw footprints of a size 12 boot - how did they break in?"

Comment: Yes, in a house youlook for a picked lock or a destroyed window. Where to look at a server?